# What does `git show --reverse` do?

Tags: git

I know that `git log --reverse` shows the log in reverse order, putting the oldest at the top and the newest at the bottom, but what does `git show --reverse` do? If I run `git show --reverse` it seems to show the same output as plain `git show`, i.e. the latest commit.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like `git show --reverse` only changes the output if you specify a range, e.g. `git show --reverse HEAD~2..`. In that case, it will behave like `git log --reverse`.

Comment: Not sure why your Q&A are downvoted, but this is correct: `git show` passes the `--reverse` option to the revision parser, where it means to reverse the order of commit ranges. Since `git show` resolves hash IDs without walking the graph by default, this only really affects range-based revision specifiers.

Answer (score -2):

The git command "git show --reverse" shows,

some data of your project like author last edited date, where the head is placed, the hash code of your last commit, last edited file , last inputted data, etc.

Comment: This does not answer the question. What you have described is what `git show` shows with and without without `--reverse`. I am asking what the difference is between plain `git show` and `git show --reverse`.